# How to remove row of array which row contain value less than 11

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Following example is in ordinary Python code. But how to do it in Tensorflow library? I want to remove row of array which row contain value less than 11. I want this coding to calculate accuracy for good prediction only.

```
a = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  0,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  10],
              [ 0, 11,  0, 13,  0, 15,  0, 17, 18,  0]])
print (a[a.max(axis=1) >= 11])
```

Comment: From [tag:tensorflow]: "**IMPORTANT**: PLEASE ADD THE LANGUAGE TAG YOU ARE DEVELOPING IN. TENSORFLOW SUPPORTS MORE THAN ONE LANGUAGE."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `tf.reduce_max` to calculate the maximum value along an axis, and `tf.boolean_mask` to subset the tensor based on the boolean condition:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.InteractiveSession()

t = tf.constant(a)

t1 = tf.boolean_mask(t, tf.reduce_max(t, axis=1) >= 11)

t1.eval()
# array([[ 0, 11,  0, 13,  0, 15,  0, 17, 18,  0]])
```

Comment: `logits_filtered = tf.boolean_mask(logits, tf.reduce_max(logits, axis=1) >= acc_filtered_r_)` ValueError: Number of mask dimensions must be specified, even if some dimensions are None. E.g. shape=[None] is ok, but shape=None is not.